# Null pointer exception is thrown when USING DEPENDENCY INJECTION in Service layer. The DAO class bean is NULL

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using Struts, hibernate. The project was working fine. Now, I used dependency injection gor creating the dao object in service layer. It isnt working. Please tell me what has gone wrong here.

```
<!-- properties declares that the contained properties form an alternate key. The name
attribute allows an alternate key to be used as the target of a property-ref. -->

<!ELEMENT properties (
    (property|many-to-one|component|dynamic-component)*
)>
    <!ATTLIST properties name CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST properties unique (true|false) "false">
    <!ATTLIST properties insert (true|false) "true">
    <!ATTLIST properties update (true|false) "true">
    <!ATTLIST properties optimistic-lock (true|false) "true">
    <!ATTLIST properties node CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!-- The parent element maps a property of the component class as a pointer back to
the owning entity. -->

<!ELEMENT parent EMPTY>
    <!ATTLIST parent name CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!-- Collection declarations nested inside a class declaration indicate a foreign key 
relationship from the collection table to the enclosing class. -->

<!ELEMENT map (
    meta*,
    subselect?,
    cache?,
    synchronize*,
    comment?,
    key, 
    (map-key|composite-map-key|map-key-many-to-many|index|composite-index|index-many-to-many|index-many-to-any), 
    (element|one-to-many|many-to-many|composite-element|many-to-any),
    loader?,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?,sql-delete-all?,
    filter*
)>
    <!ATTLIST map name CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST map access CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST map table CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                             <!-- default: name -->
    <!ATTLIST map schema CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                            <!-- default: none -->
    <!ATTLIST map subselect CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST map catalog CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                           <!-- default: none -->
    <!ATTLIST map lazy (true|false|extra) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST map mutable (true|false) "true">
    <!ATTLIST map inverse (true|false) "false">
    <!ATTLIST map sort CDATA "unsorted">                                                            <!-- unsorted|natural|"comparator class", default: unsorted -->
    <!ATTLIST map cascade CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST map order-by CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                          <!-- default: none -->
    <!ATTLIST map where CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                             <!-- default: none -->
    <!ATTLIST map batch-size CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST map outer-join (true|false|auto) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST map fetch (join|select|subselect) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST map check CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                             <!-- default: none -->  
    <!ATTLIST map persister CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                     
    <!ATTLIST map collection-type CDATA #IMPLIED>   
    <!ATTLIST map optimistic-lock (true|false) "true">      <!-- only supported for properties of a class (not component) -->
    <!ATTLIST map node CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST map embed-xml (true|false) "true">

<!ELEMENT set (
    meta*,
    subselect?,
    cache?,
    synchronize*,
    comment?,
    key, 
    (element|one-to-many|many-to-many|composite-element|many-to-any),
    loader?,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?,sql-delete-all?,
    filter*
)>
    <!ATTLIST set name CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST set access CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST set table CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                             <!-- default: name -->
    <!ATTLIST set schema CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                            <!-- default: none -->
    <!ATTLIST set catalog CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                           <!-- default: none -->
    <!ATTLIST set subselect CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST set lazy (true|false|extra) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST set sort CDATA "unsorted">                                                            <!-- unsorted|natural|"comparator class" -->
    <!ATTLIST set inverse (true|false) "false">
    <!ATTLIST set mutable (true|false) "true">
    <!ATTLIST set cascade CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST set order-by CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                          <!-- default: none -->
    <!ATTLIST set where CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                             <!-- default: none -->
    <!ATTLIST set batch-size CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST set outer-join (true|false|auto) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST set fetch (join|select|subselect) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST set persister CDATA #IMPLIED> 
    <!ATTLIST set collection-type CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                       
    <!ATTLIST set check CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                             <!-- default: none -->
    <!ATTLIST set optimistic-lock (true|false) "true">      <!-- only supported for properties of a class (not component) -->
    <!ATTLIST set node CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST set embed-xml (true|false) "true">

<!ELEMENT bag (
    meta*,
    subselect?,
    cache?,
    synchronize*,
    comment?,
    key, 
    (element|one-to-many|many-to-many|composite-element|many-to-any),
    loader?,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?,sql-delete-all?,
    filter*
)>
    <!ATTLIST bag name CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST bag access CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST bag table CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                             <!-- default: name -->
    <!ATTLIST bag schema CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                            <!-- default: none -->
    <!ATTLIST bag catalog CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                           <!-- default: none -->
    <!ATTLIST bag subselect CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST bag lazy (true|false|extra) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST bag inverse (true|false) "false">
    <!ATTLIST bag mutable (true|false) "true">
    <!ATTLIST bag cascade CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST bag order-by CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                          <!-- default: none -->
    <!ATTLIST bag where CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                             <!-- default: none -->
    <!ATTLIST bag batch-size CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST bag outer-join (true|false|auto) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST bag fetch (join|select|subselect) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST bag persister CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                         
    <!ATTLIST bag collection-type CDATA #IMPLIED>   
    <!ATTLIST bag check CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                             <!-- default: none -->
    <!ATTLIST bag optimistic-lock (true|false) "true">      <!-- only supported for properties of a class (not component) -->
    <!ATTLIST bag node CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST bag embed-xml (true|false) "true">

<!ELEMENT idbag (
    meta*,
    subselect?,
    cache?,
    synchronize*,
    comment?,
    collection-id,
    key, 
    (element|many-to-many|composite-element|many-to-any),
    loader?,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?,sql-delete-all?,
    filter*
)>
    <!ATTLIST idbag name CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST idbag access CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST idbag table CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                           <!-- default: name -->
    <!ATTLIST idbag schema CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                          <!-- default: none -->
    <!ATTLIST idbag catalog CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                         <!-- default: none -->
    <!ATTLIST idbag subselect CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST idbag lazy (true|false|extra) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST idbag mutable (true|false) "true">
    <!ATTLIST idbag cascade CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST idbag order-by CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                        <!-- default: none -->
    <!ATTLIST idbag where CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                           <!-- default: none -->
    <!ATTLIST idbag batch-size CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST idbag outer-join (true|false|auto) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST idbag fetch (join|select|subselect) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST idbag persister CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                           
    <!ATTLIST idbag collection-type CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST idbag check CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                           <!-- default: none -->
    <!ATTLIST idbag optimistic-lock (true|false) "true">    <!-- only supported for properties of a class (not component) -->
    <!ATTLIST idbag node CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST idbag embed-xml (true|false) "true">

<!ELEMENT list (
    meta*,
    subselect?,
    cache?,
    synchronize*,
    comment?,
    key, 
    (index|list-index), 
    (element|one-to-many|many-to-many|composite-element|many-to-any),
    loader?,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?,sql-delete-all?,
    filter*
)>
    <!ATTLIST list name CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST list access CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST list table CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                            <!-- default: name -->
    <!ATTLIST list schema CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                           <!-- default: none -->
    <!ATTLIST list catalog CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                          <!-- default: none -->
    <!ATTLIST list subselect CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST list lazy (true|false|extra) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST list inverse (true|false) "false">
    <!ATTLIST list mutable (true|false) "true">
    <!ATTLIST list cascade CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST list where CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                            <!-- default: none -->
    <!ATTLIST list batch-size CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST list outer-join (true|false|auto) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST list fetch (join|select|subselect) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST list persister CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                                
    <!ATTLIST list collection-type CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST list check CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                            <!-- default: none -->
    <!ATTLIST list optimistic-lock (true|false) "true">     <!-- only supported for properties of a class (not component) -->
    <!ATTLIST list node CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST list embed-xml (true|false) "true">

<!ELEMENT array (
    meta*,
    subselect?,
    cache?,
    synchronize*,
    comment?,
    key, 
    (index|list-index), 
    (element|one-to-many|many-to-many|composite-element|many-to-any),
    loader?,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?,sql-delete-all?
)>
    <!ATTLIST array name CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST array access CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST array table CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                           <!-- default: name -->
    <!ATTLIST array schema CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                          <!-- default: none -->
    <!ATTLIST array catalog CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                         <!-- default: none -->
    <!ATTLIST array subselect CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST array inverse (true|false) "false">
    <!ATTLIST array mutable (true|false) "true">
    <!ATTLIST array element-class CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST array cascade CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST array where CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                           <!-- default: none -->
    <!ATTLIST array batch-size CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST array outer-join (true|false|auto) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST array fetch (join|select|subselect) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST array persister CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                           
    <!ATTLIST array collection-type CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST array check CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                           <!-- default: none -->
    <!ATTLIST array optimistic-lock (true|false) "true">    <!-- only supported for properties of a class (not component) -->
    <!ATTLIST array node CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST array embed-xml (true|false) "true">

<!ELEMENT primitive-array (
    meta*, 
    subselect?,
    cache?, 
    synchronize*,
    comment?,
    key, 
    (index|list-index), 
    element,
    loader?,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?,sql-delete-all?
)>
    <!ATTLIST primitive-array name CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST primitive-array access CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST primitive-array table CDATA #IMPLIED>                                 <!-- default: name -->
    <!ATTLIST primitive-array schema CDATA #IMPLIED>                                <!-- default: none -->
    <!ATTLIST primitive-array catalog CDATA #IMPLIED>                               <!-- default: none -->
    <!ATTLIST primitive-array subselect CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST primitive-array mutable (true|false) "true">
    <!ATTLIST primitive-array where CDATA #IMPLIED>                                 <!-- default: none -->
    <!ATTLIST primitive-array batch-size CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST primitive-array outer-join (true|false|auto) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST primitive-array fetch (join|select|subselect) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST primitive-array persister CDATA #IMPLIED>                                                             
    <!ATTLIST primitive-array collection-type CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST primitive-array check CDATA #IMPLIED>                                 <!-- default: none -->
    <!ATTLIST primitive-array optimistic-lock (true|false) "true">      <!-- only supported for properties of a class (not component) -->
    <!ATTLIST primitive-array node CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST primitive-array embed-xml (true|false) "true">

<!-- Declares the element type of a collection of basic type -->

<!ELEMENT element ( (column|formula)*, type? )>
    <!ATTLIST element column CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST element node CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST element formula CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST element type CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST element length CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST element precision CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST element scale CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST element not-null (true|false) "false">
    <!ATTLIST element unique (true|false) "false">

<!-- One to many association. This tag declares the entity-class
element type of a collection and specifies a one-to-many relational model -->

<!ELEMENT one-to-many EMPTY>
    <!ATTLIST one-to-many class CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST one-to-many not-found (exception|ignore) "exception">
    <!ATTLIST one-to-many node CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST one-to-many embed-xml (true|false) "true">
    <!ATTLIST one-to-many entity-name CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!-- No column declaration attributes required in this case. The primary
    key column of the associated class is already mapped elsewhere.-->

<!-- Many to many association. This tag declares the entity-class
element type of a collection and specifies a many-to-many relational model -->

<!ELEMENT many-to-many (meta*,(column|formula)*,filter*)>
    <!ATTLIST many-to-many class CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST many-to-many node CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST many-to-many embed-xml (true|false) "true">
    <!ATTLIST many-to-many entity-name CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST many-to-many column CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST many-to-many formula CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST many-to-many not-found (exception|ignore) "exception">
    <!ATTLIST many-to-many outer-join (true|false|auto) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST many-to-many fetch (join|select) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST many-to-many lazy (false|proxy) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST many-to-many foreign-key CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST many-to-many unique (true|false) "false">
    <!ATTLIST many-to-many where CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST many-to-many order-by CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST many-to-many property-ref CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!-- A composite element allows a collection to hold instances of an arbitrary 
class, without the requirement of joining to an entity table. Composite elements
have component semantics - no shared references and ad hoc null value semantics. 
Composite elements may not hold nested collections. -->

<!ELEMENT composite-element ( 
    (meta*),
    parent?,
    tuplizer*,
    (property|many-to-one|any|nested-composite-element)* 
)>
    <!ATTLIST composite-element class CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST composite-element node CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT nested-composite-element ( 
    parent?,
    tuplizer*,
    (property|many-to-one|any|nested-composite-element)* 
)>
    <!ATTLIST nested-composite-element class CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST nested-composite-element name CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST nested-composite-element access CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST nested-composite-element node CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!-- Declares the column name of a foreign key. -->

<!ELEMENT key (column*)>
    <!ATTLIST key column CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST key property-ref CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST key foreign-key CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST key on-delete (cascade|noaction) "noaction">
    <!ATTLIST key not-null (true|false) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST key update (true|false) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST key unique (true|false) #IMPLIED>

<!-- Declares the type and column mapping for a collection index (array or
list index, or key of a map). -->

<!ELEMENT list-index (column?)>
    <!ATTLIST list-index column CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST list-index base CDATA "0">

<!ELEMENT map-key ((column|formula)*,type?)>
    <!ATTLIST map-key column CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST map-key formula CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST map-key type CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST map-key length CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST map-key node CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT index (column*)>
    <!ATTLIST index column CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST index type CDATA #IMPLIED>            <!-- required for maps -->
    <!ATTLIST index length CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!-- Many to many association mapped to the key of a map. ie. a map keyed
on entities. -->

<!ELEMENT map-key-many-to-many ((column|formula)*)>
    <!ATTLIST map-key-many-to-many class CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST map-key-many-to-many entity-name CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST map-key-many-to-many column CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST map-key-many-to-many formula CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST map-key-many-to-many foreign-key CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT index-many-to-many (column*)>
    <!ATTLIST index-many-to-many class CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST index-many-to-many entity-name CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST index-many-to-many column CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST index-many-to-many foreign-key CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!-- Composite index of a map ie. a map keyed on components. -->

<!ELEMENT composite-map-key ( (key-property|key-many-to-one)+ )>
    <!ATTLIST composite-map-key class CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT composite-index ( (key-property|key-many-to-one)+ )>
    <!ATTLIST composite-index class CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!-- A "many to any" defines a polymorphic association to any table 
with the given identifier type. The first listed column is a VARCHAR column 
holding the name of the class (for that row). -->

<!ELEMENT many-to-any (meta-value*,column, column+)>
    <!ATTLIST many-to-any id-type CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST many-to-any meta-type CDATA #IMPLIED>         <!--- default: Hibernate.CLASS -->

<!ELEMENT index-many-to-any (column, column+)>
    <!ATTLIST index-many-to-any id-type CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST index-many-to-any meta-type CDATA #IMPLIED>   <!--- default: Hibernate.CLASS -->

<!ELEMENT collection-id (meta*, column*, generator)>
    <!ATTLIST collection-id column CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST collection-id type CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST collection-id length CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!-- Generators generate unique identifiers. The class attribute specifies a Java 
class implementing an id generation algorithm. -->

<!ELEMENT generator (param*)>
    <!ATTLIST generator class CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT param (#PCDATA)>
    <!ATTLIST param name CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!-- The column element is an alternative to column attributes and required for 
mapping associations to classes with composite ids. -->

<!ELEMENT column (comment?)>
    <!ATTLIST column name CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST column length CDATA #IMPLIED>                     <!-- default: 255 -->
    <!ATTLIST column precision CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST column scale CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST column not-null (true|false) #IMPLIED>            <!-- default: false (except for id properties) -->
    <!ATTLIST column unique (true|false) #IMPLIED>              <!-- default: false (except for id properties) -->
    <!ATTLIST column unique-key CDATA #IMPLIED>                 <!-- default: no unique key -->
    <!ATTLIST column sql-type CDATA #IMPLIED>                   <!-- override default column type for hibernate type -->
    <!ATTLIST column index CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST column check CDATA #IMPLIED>                      <!-- default: no check constraint -->
    <!ATTLIST column default CDATA #IMPLIED>                    <!-- default: no default value -->
    <!ATTLIST column read CDATA #IMPLIED>                       <!-- default: column name -->
    <!ATTLIST column write CDATA #IMPLIED>                      <!-- default: parameter placeholder ('?') -->

<!-- The formula and subselect elements allow us to map derived properties and 
entities. -->

<!ELEMENT formula (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT subselect (#PCDATA)>

<!-- The cache element enables caching of an entity class. -->
<!ELEMENT cache EMPTY>
    <!ATTLIST cache usage (read-only|read-write|nonstrict-read-write|transactional) #REQUIRED>              
    <!ATTLIST cache region CDATA #IMPLIED>                      <!-- default: class or collection role name -->
    <!ATTLIST cache include (all|non-lazy) "all">

<!-- The comment element allows definition of a database table or column comment. -->

<!ELEMENT comment (#PCDATA)>

<!-- The loader element allows specification of a named query to be used for fetching
an entity or collection -->

<!ELEMENT loader EMPTY>
    <!ATTLIST loader query-ref CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!-- The query element declares a named Hibernate query string -->

<!ELEMENT query (#PCDATA|query-param)*>
    <!ATTLIST query name CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST query flush-mode (auto|never|always) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST query cacheable (true|false) "false">
    <!ATTLIST query cache-region CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST query fetch-size CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST query timeout CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST query cache-mode (get|ignore|normal|put|refresh) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST query read-only (true|false) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST query comment CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!-- The sql-query element declares a named SQL query string -->

<!ELEMENT sql-query (#PCDATA|return-scalar|return|return-join|load-collection|synchronize|query-param)*>
    <!ATTLIST sql-query name CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST sql-query resultset-ref CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST sql-query flush-mode (auto|never|always) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST sql-query cacheable (true|false) "false">
    <!ATTLIST sql-query cache-region CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST sql-query fetch-size CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST sql-query timeout CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST sql-query cache-mode (get|ignore|normal|put|refresh) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST sql-query read-only (true|false) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST sql-query comment CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST sql-query callable (true|false) "false">

<!-- The query-param element is used only by tools that generate
finder methods for named queries -->

<!ELEMENT query-param EMPTY>
    <!ATTLIST query-param name CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST query-param type CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!-- The resultset element declares a named resultset mapping definition for SQL queries -->
<!ELEMENT resultset (return-scalar|return|return-join|load-collection)*>
    <!ATTLIST resultset name CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!--
    Defines a return component for a sql-query.  Alias refers to the alias
    used in the actual sql query; lock-mode specifies the locking to be applied
    when the query is executed.  The class, collection, and role attributes are mutually exclusive;
    class refers to the class name of a "root entity" in the object result; collection refers
    to a collection of a given class and is used to define custom sql to load that owned collection
    and takes the form "ClassName.propertyName"; role refers to the property path for an eager fetch
    and takes the form "owningAlias.propertyName"
-->
<!ELEMENT return (return-discriminator?,return-property)*>
    <!ATTLIST return alias CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST return entity-name CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST return class CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST return lock-mode (none|read|upgrade|upgrade-nowait|write) "read"> 

<!ELEMENT return-property (return-column*)> 
    <!ATTLIST return-property name CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST return-property column CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT return-column EMPTY> 
    <!ATTLIST return-column name CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT return-discriminator EMPTY> 
    <!ATTLIST return-discriminator column CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT return-join (return-property)*> 
    <!ATTLIST return-join alias CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST return-join property CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST return-join lock-mode (none|read|upgrade|upgrade-nowait|write) "read">

<!ELEMENT load-collection (return-property)*> 
    <!ATTLIST load-collection alias CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST load-collection role CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST load-collection lock-mode (none|read|upgrade|upgrade-nowait|write) "read">

<!ELEMENT return-scalar EMPTY>
    <!ATTLIST return-scalar column CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST return-scalar type CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT synchronize EMPTY>
    <!ATTLIST synchronize table CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!-- custom sql operations -->
<!ELEMENT sql-insert (#PCDATA)>
    <!ATTLIST sql-insert callable (true|false) "false">
    <!ATTLIST sql-insert check (none|rowcount|param) #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT sql-update (#PCDATA)>
    <!ATTLIST sql-update callable (true|false) "false">
    <!ATTLIST sql-update check (none|rowcount|param) #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT sql-delete (#PCDATA)>
    <!ATTLIST sql-delete callable (true|false) "false">
    <!ATTLIST sql-delete check (none|rowcount|param) #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT sql-delete-all (#PCDATA)>
    <!ATTLIST sql-delete-all callable (true|false) "false">
    <!ATTLIST sql-delete-all check (none|rowcount|param) #IMPLIED>

<!--
    Element for defining "auxiliary" database objects.  Must be one of two forms:

    #1 :
        <database-object>
            <definition class="CustomClassExtendingAuxiliaryObject"/>
        </database-object>

    #2 :
        <database-object>
            <create>CREATE OR REPLACE ....</create>
            <drop>DROP ....</drop>
        </database-object>
-->
<!ELEMENT database-object ( (definition|(create,drop)), dialect-scope* )>

<!ELEMENT definition EMPTY>
    <!ATTLIST definition class CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT create (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT drop (#PCDATA)>

<!--
    dialect-scope element allows scoping auxiliary-objects to a particular
    Hibernate dialect implementation.
-->
<!ELEMENT dialect-scope (#PCDATA)>
    <!ATTLIST dialect-scope name CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

I am using Struts, hibernate. The project was working fine. Now, I used dependency injection gor creating the dao object in service layer. It isnt working. Please tell me what has gone wrong here.

Comment: I am fully confuse with your code. you configure the XML for LeaveService and LeaveDAO object. But i didn't find where you use that in your code. Please highlighted the same if i miss any place.

Comment: In the service Layer:                                                                                                                    LeaveDAO    leaveDAO; // this is the dependency injection

Comment: Please see the service Layer janny..Thats where ive used it! I've used the DAO layer bean in my service layer to call the dao layer's methods>

Comment: You need to add getter method for leaveDAO.

Comment: done. Still same error

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the Spring Container by enabling the ContextLoaderListener in your web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: And, when i do that.. I am gettin 404 error. thats why  i had removed it.

Comment: Spring cannot work without the ContextLoaderListener. You will need to analyse the 404 error properly by debuging or checking of your logfile.

Answer (score 0):

Add below listener in web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

In LeaveService.java, add below constructor: Spring while creating bean for LeaveService, it will call below constructor and will set the value for field leaveDAO

```
 LeaveService(LeaveDAO  leaveDAO ){
this.leaveDAO = leaveDAO ;
}
```